# Rails - prevent input_tag from making an ajax call when enter is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have a form_tag with one input field as so:

```
<%= form_tag "raijax", method: 'get', remote: true, :onsubmit => "return false;", id: "form-tag" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag "val", nil, autocomplete: :off %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to stop the form from making an ajax call by returing false in `onsubmit`, but am having no such luck.

Through other answers it is suggested to replace `onsubmit` with `onclick`, and i suspect that would work for their case if the form had a submit button, because for me it just works when I click the field tag, not on submission, obviously.

I've succesfully gotten the form to not submit, by using jquery by doing:

```
$("#form-tag").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

But is there anyway to do this with the `onsubmit` attribute?

Using Rails v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prevent the "enter" key from doing anything in the input

```
<%= form_tag "raijax", method: 'get', remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "val", nil, autocomplete: :off, onkeydown:"if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;" %>
<% end %>
```